# C++ Finite State Machine - follow-up

Tags: c++, c++11, template, state-machine

This question is a follow-up from [Object Oriented Finite State Machine](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/104489/49895). I vastly improved commenting and followed [the suggestions from the answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/104579/49895). Additionally, I improved my tests and did some more refactoring.

At this point, I still want to know what I could be doing better in my code. How could I better follow C++ conventions? I purposely named my class in lowercase to mimic the standard library, but is that a bad idea? I also moved a lot of code from the `cpp`/`impl` file into the header file; did I go too far? Also, to use my function binding mechanism, it is often required to use a pointer (as can be seen in my test file). This feels ugly; is there a better way?

Additionally, what could make the code run faster?

**fsm.hpp**

```
#pragma once

/*
A library to define a Finite State Machine (fsm).
*/

#include <map> // std::map
#include <tuple> // std::pair
#include <vector> // std::vector
#include <functional> // std::function

/*
A namespace for extra library classes / functions.
*/
namespace extra
{
    /*
    An implementation of an fsm.
    This class implements a Moore state machine.
    Defining mappings, outputs, and bindings must be done via fsm::builder.

    In addition to simply implementing a state machine, this class keeps track
    of the inputs you feed it in an accumulator.
    */
    template<
        typename Input, // The input that the fsm expects to receive
        typename Output, // The output that the fsm will output
        typename State // The type of state that the fsm will walk through. Recommended to be an enum
    >
    class fsm
    {
        friend class builder;
    public:
        class builder;

        /*
        Creates a blank fsm. This is not useful for actually doing anything, but
        default constructors are necessary for many use cases
        */
        fsm() {}
        /* Advance the fsm to the next state. */
        void advance(const Input&);
        /* Get the output of the fsm at the current state. */
        Output get_output() const { return details.output_map.at(cur_state); }
        /* Get whether the fsm can return an output */
        bool has_output() const { return details.output_map.count(cur_state) > 0; }
        /* Get the current state of the fsm */
        State get_current_state() const { return cur_state; }
        /*
        Get the current accumulator for the fsm. This contains all inputs from the
        last reset_accumulator() until now.
        */
        const std::vector<Input>& get_accumulator() const { return accumulator; }
        /* Resets (ie clears) the accumulator */
        void reset_accumulator() { accumulator.clear(); }
        /* Resets this finite state machine such that it's as if it was just created. */
        void reset()
        {
            cur_state = initial_state;
            reset_accumulator();
        }
    private:
        State initial_state;
        State cur_state;
        std::vector<Input> accumulator;
        builder details;

        fsm(builder builder)
            : initial_state{ builder.initial_state }
            , cur_state{ builder.initial_state }
            , details{ builder }
        {}
    };

    /*
    A class for building an fsm.
    */
    template<typename Input, typename Output, typename State>
    class fsm<Input, Output, State>::builder
    {
        friend class fsm<Input, Output, State>;
    public:
        builder() {}
        builder(State starting_state) : initial_state{ starting_state } {}

        /* defines the initial state of the fsm */
        builder & starting_state(State state) { initial_state = state; return *this; }
        /*
        Binds an entrance into the given state to the given callback. The Input argument to the
        callback is the input that made the machine go into the given state
        */
        builder & bind(State toBindTo, std::function<void(Input)> callback)
        {
            state_bindings.emplace(toBindTo, callback);
            return *this;
        }
        /* Map from `from` to `to` when receiving the input `trigger` */
        builder & map(State from, Input trigger, State to)
        {
            map(from, [trigger](Input in) { return trigger == in; }, to);
            return *this;
        }
        /* Map from `from` to `to` when receiving any input whatsoever. Lowest priority. */
        builder & map(State from, State to)
        {
            map(from, [](Input) { return true; }, to);
            return *this;
        }
        /* Map from `from` to `to` when the given function returns true */
        builder & map(State from, std::function<bool(Input)> guard, State to)
        {
            auto & functionsForState = function_state_map[from];
            functionsForState.emplace_back(std::make_pair(guard, to));
            return *this;
        }
        /* Return `result` when the fsm is at the current output */
        builder & map_output(State from, Output output)
        {
            output_map.emplace(from, output);
            return *this;
        }
        /* Build the finite state machine */
        fsm<Input, Output, State> build() { return fsm{ *this }; }

    private:
        State initial_state;
        std::map<State, std::function<void(Input)>> state_bindings;
        std::map<State, std::vector<std::pair<std::function<bool(Input)>, State>>> function_state_map;
        std::map<State, Output> output_map;
    };
}
#include "fsm.impl"
```

**fsm.impl**

```
#pragma once // This file is included within "fsm.h", so we need to ensure we don't get circular inclusion

#include "fsm.hpp"

/* Advance the fsm to the next state. */
template<typename Input, typename Output, typename State>
void extra::fsm<Input, Output, State>::advance(const Input & input)
{
    accumulator.push_back(input);

    auto & allApplicableFunctions = details.function_state_map.find(cur_state); // Look at all mappings from this state

    if (allApplicableFunctions != details.function_state_map.end()) {
        for (auto & mapping : allApplicableFunctions->second) { // For every mapping from the current state,
            auto & acceptFunction = mapping.first;
            bool acceptState = (acceptFunction)(input);         // see if it takes this input.

            if (acceptState) {              // If the given mapping takes this input,
                cur_state = mapping.second; // go to the mapping's destination.

                auto binding = details.state_bindings.find(cur_state); // If the given state that we went to
                if (binding != details.state_bindings.end()) {         // has a binding,
                    binding->second(input);                 // call that binding.
                }
                return; // We already went to a state, so quit
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**fsm_test.cpp** (uses googletest)

```
#include <vector>

#include "fsm.hpp"

#include "gtest/gtest.h"

using namespace extra;

enum State
{
    INIT, S1, S2, S3, S4
};

class fsm_test : public ::testing::Test
{
protected:
    virtual void SetUp()
    {
        auto * count = &s2_count;
        machine = fsm<int, int, State>::builder(State::INIT)
            .map(INIT, 1, S1)                                   // +--------+ <--0-- +------+
            .map(S1, 1, S2)                                     // | INIT:0 | --1--> | S1:1 |
            .map(S2, 1, S1)                                     // +--------+        +------+
            .map(S2, 2, S3)                                     //  ^ ^   +-1---------^ |
            .map(S3, 1, S4)                                     //  +-|-1-|----+        1
            .map(S4, 1, INIT)                                   //  | 0   1    |        |
            .map(S4, [](int input) { return input > 2; }, INIT) // ++ |   |    1        |
            .map(S1, 0, INIT)                                   // | +------+  |        |
            .map(S2, 0, INIT)                                   // | | S2:2*|<----------+
            .map(S3, 0, INIT)                                   // | +------+  |
            .map(S4, 0, INIT)                                   // |  |  ^     +--------+
            .map(S3, S2)                                        // |  2  |              |
            .map_output(INIT, 0)                                // |  | [*]        [0, 1, >2] 
            .map_output(S1, 1)                                  // 0  v  |              |
            .map_output(S2, 2)                                  // | +------+        +------+ 
            .map_output(S3, 3)                                  // +-| S3:3 | --1--> |  S4  | (no output on S4)
            .bind(S2, [count](int) { (*count)++; })             //   +------+        +------+
            .build();                                           // * Increment count on entrance to S2
    }

    fsm<int, int, State> machine;
    size_t s2_count;
};

TEST_F(fsm_test, canAdvanceStates)
{
    machine.advance(10); // INIT -> INIT
    EXPECT_EQ(INIT, machine.get_current_state());

    machine.advance(1); // INIT -> S1
    EXPECT_EQ(S1, machine.get_current_state());

    machine.advance(1); // S1 -> S2 (count++)
    EXPECT_EQ(S2, machine.get_current_state());

    machine.advance(1); // S2 -> S1
    EXPECT_EQ(S1, machine.get_current_state());

    machine.advance(1); // S1 -> S2 (count++)
    machine.advance(2); // S2 -> S3
    EXPECT_EQ(S3, machine.get_current_state());

    machine.advance(14); // S3 -> S2 (count++)
    EXPECT_EQ(S2, machine.get_current_state());

    machine.advance(2); // S2 -> S3
    machine.advance(1); // S3 -> S4
    EXPECT_EQ(S4, machine.get_current_state());

    machine.advance(2); // S4 -> S4 (implicit)
    EXPECT_EQ(S4, machine.get_current_state());

    machine.advance(1); // S4 -> INIT
    EXPECT_EQ(INIT, machine.get_current_state());

    machine.advance(1); // INIT -> S1
    machine.advance(1); // S1 -> S2 (count++)
    machine.advance(0); // S2 -> INIT
    EXPECT_EQ(INIT, machine.get_current_state());

    machine.advance(1); // INIT -> S1
    machine.advance(1); // S1 -> S2 (count++)
    machine.advance(2); // S2 -> S3
    machine.advance(1); // S3 -> S4
    ASSERT_EQ(S4, machine.get_current_state()); // Just to be sure

    machine.advance(10); // S4 -> S1
    EXPECT_EQ(INIT, machine.get_current_state());

    EXPECT_EQ(5, s2_count);
}

TEST_F(fsm_test, canReturnCorrectOutput)
{
    EXPECT_TRUE(machine.has_output());
    EXPECT_EQ(0, machine.get_output());

    machine.advance(1);
    EXPECT_TRUE(machine.has_output());
    EXPECT_EQ(1, machine.get_output());

    machine.advance(1);
    EXPECT_TRUE(machine.has_output());
    EXPECT_EQ(2, machine.get_output());

    machine.advance(2);
    EXPECT_TRUE(machine.has_output());
    EXPECT_EQ(3, machine.get_output());

    machine.advance(1);
    EXPECT_FALSE(machine.has_output());
    EXPECT_ANY_THROW(machine.get_output()); // S4 has no output; Throws.

    machine.advance(1);
    EXPECT_TRUE(machine.has_output());
    EXPECT_EQ(0, machine.get_output());
}

TEST_F(fsm_test, canReturnAccumulators)
{
    std::vector<int> accumulator;
    ASSERT_EQ(accumulator, machine.get_accumulator());
    accumulator.push_back(1);
    machine.advance(1);

    ASSERT_EQ(accumulator, machine.get_accumulator());
    accumulator.push_back(2);
    machine.advance(2);

    ASSERT_EQ(accumulator, machine.get_accumulator());
    accumulator.push_back(-1);
    machine.advance(-1);

    ASSERT_EQ(accumulator, machine.get_accumulator());
    accumulator.clear();
    machine.reset_accumulator();

    ASSERT_EQ(accumulator, machine.get_accumulator());
    accumulator.push_back(1);
    machine.advance(1);

    ASSERT_EQ(accumulator, machine.get_accumulator());
    accumulator.push_back(2);
    machine.advance(2);

    ASSERT_EQ(accumulator, machine.get_accumulator());
    accumulator.push_back(-1);
    machine.advance(-1);

    ASSERT_EQ(accumulator, machine.get_accumulator());
}

TEST_F(fsm_test, canReset)
{
    machine.advance(1);
    ASSERT_NE(INIT, machine.get_current_state()) << "State machine didn't advance states";

    machine.reset();
    EXPECT_EQ(INIT, machine.get_current_state()) << "Didn't reset to initial_state";
    EXPECT_TRUE(machine.get_accumulator().empty()) << "Didn't clear accumulator";
}
```